# Add two voltage signal and Convert output to current signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, adder

I generated two different Signals using DDS and now I want to add them and convert output signal to current signal without any distortion in it? what is the best and accurate part I can use ?

Comment: Without any distortion is impossible. What does "best" mean?

Comment: I mean the frequency of generated signals remain constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use opamp summer circuit for adding two signals.See the link below for detailed explanation.
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_4.html

Then again use opamp at the ouput stage to convert V(voltage) to I(current).(V to I converter) .see the link below
https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/text/chapter-4

Ask if you have any doubt regarding this explanation